# Python and SQLite - how to "escape" string on SELECT and INSERT?

Tags: python, sqlite, escaping

I'm trying to search for and (if not found) insert passwords in one of the tables that I have set up, but **if the password ends with a single quote** or .. there were a couple of other symbols, too .. it fails.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO passwords (password, md5) VALUES (?, ?)", password, md5)
```

I have tried double quotes, single quotes, .. What else?

Comment: Escaping is not the problem. You need to make the argument a tuple, but you have listed the variables as multiple arguments. See the linked question.

Comment: Thank you! Magic .. Works now!